# MySQL, how to get the string with highest suffix

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table is:

[image]

After Query: 

`` SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `identifier` LIKE '000123_%' ``

I get:

[image]

How to get the row with highest suffix, i.e: 000123_**5** with query.

Comment: It would be far better to normalise your data

Comment: In MySQL, I don't know, but with PHP (you enabled the tag) I would post-process the results from MySQL to sort the rows. From example using the explode function to isolate the suffix.

Comment: If the suffix is only 1 digit: `ORDER BY REVERSE(identifier) DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: the value of `identifier` could be `^\d+_\d+$` @AlexHowansky

Answer (score 1):

Why dont create the function SPLIT_STRING at your DB like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `SPLIT_STRING`(
    str VARCHAR(255) ,
    delim VARCHAR(12) ,
    pos INT
) RETURNS VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8 RETURN REPLACE(
    SUBSTRING(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(str , delim , pos) ,
        CHAR_LENGTH(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(str , delim , pos - 1)
        ) + 1
    ) ,
    delim ,
    ''
);
```

And later you can call her from your query to get the last characters:

```
-- Example table 
CREATE TABLE `test`(
    `keywords` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;

INSERT INTO `test`(`keywords`)
VALUES
    (
        'keyword 1,keyword 2, keyword 3,     keyword 4'
    );

-- Example query
SELECT
    -- keyword 1
    SPLIT_STRING(`keywords`,',',1) AS keyword_1,
    -- keyword 4, NOT trimmed
    SPLIT_STRING(`keywords`,',',4) AS keyword_4,
    -- keyword 4, trimmed
    trim(SPLIT_STRING(`keywords`,',',4)) AS keyword_4_trimmed
FROM `test`;
```

Using it at your example:

```
SELECT SPLIT_STRING(`identifier`,'_',2)  as identifier2,* FROM `table` 
WHERE `identifier` LIKE '000123_%'
ORDER BY SPLIT_STRING(`identifier`,'_',2) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular answer, you could use RIGHT(identifier,1) to take the rightmost character. Then you would take the MAX() of the right to find the highest. However, if the suffix would end up being 1 *or more* characters then you would need to find the right regex to capture the characters that come after the last underscore and then take the MAX() of that group.

Comment: the value of `identifier` could be `^\d+_\d+$`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query, where you pick the highest value by comparation from all the right side values of the varchar 'identifier'. My code may not work exactly as I don't have a pc here. Good luck!

```
SELECT *, select RIGHT(identifier,1) as rvalue  FROM `table` WHERE `identifier` LIKE '000123_%' and rvalue >= ALL (SELECT RIGHT(identifier,1) as rvalue  FROM `table`) t
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for a single group of rows you can apply:

```
order by char_length(identifier) desc, identifier desc 
limit 1
```

Longer string means larger numbers...